# ListView content update (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, updating

I have a grouped ListView. The content of the ListView is not updated when adding a new item. How can i fix it? Here is my code:

Exercise class:

```
    public class Exercise : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum muscleGroups
    {
        None,
        Back,
        Chest
    }

    public Exercise() { }

    private string title { get; set; }
    private muscleGroups muscleGroup { get; set; }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            if (title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    public muscleGroups MuscleGroup
    {
        get { return muscleGroup; }
        set
        {
            if (muscleGroup != value)
            {
                muscleGroup = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MuscleGroup");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

class for grouping an items:

```
    public class ExerciseGrouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Name { get; private set; }

    public ExerciseGrouping(K name, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Name = name;
        foreach (T item in items)
            Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

adding grouping items into the ListView (names exercisesList), grouping by the value of MuscleGroup property:

```
            Exercises = new ObservableCollection<Exercise>
        {
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 1", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Chest},
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 2", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Chest},
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 3", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Back},
            new Exercise {Title="Exercise 4", MuscleGroup = Exercise.muscleGroups.Back}
        };

        var groups = Exercises.GroupBy(p => p.MuscleGroup).Select(g => new ExerciseGrouping<Exercise.muscleGroups, Exercise>(g.Key, g));
        ExerciseGroups = new ObservableCollection<ExerciseGrouping<Exercise.muscleGroups, Exercise>>(groups);

        //exercisesList.BindingContext = Exercises;
        exercisesList.BindingContext = ExerciseGroups;
```

When adding new item, how can i update content of ListView?
Thanks in advance.

Code to adding new items (i have another page ExercisePage to edit or add new items):

```
    public partial class ExercisePage : ContentPage
{
    bool edited = true;
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

    public ExercisePage (Exercise exercise)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Exercise = exercise;
        if (exercise == null)
        {
            Exercise = new Exercise();
            edited = false;
        }

        this.BindingContext = Exercise;
    }

    async void SaveExercise(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await Navigation.PopAsync();

        if (edited == false)
        {
            NavigationPage navPage = (NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
            IReadOnlyList<Page> navStack = navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;
            MainPage homePage = navStack[navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1] as MainPage;

            if (homePage != null)
            {
                homePage.AddExercise(Exercise);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how specifically are you adding new items?

Comment: is that page adding a new Item to the same ObservableCollection that your list is bound to?

Comment: @Jason, I've edited text of my question (add code). Don't know ho to add code in the comments for the new line.

Comment: @Jason, when i change exercise's Title, i see changes in the ListView. But when i change MuscleGroup property, item doesn't move to another group of ListView. The problem is how to update ListView.

Comment: the data isn't going to regroup itself automatically.  You'll have to do that

Comment: I understand, but don't know when and how i should do it. Maybe in OnAppearing()?

Comment: I did it!         `protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var groups = Exercises.GroupBy(p => p.MuscleGroup).Select(g => new ExerciseGrouping<Exercise.muscleGroups, Exercise>(g.Key, g));
            ExerciseGroups = new ObservableCollection<ExerciseGrouping<Exercise.muscleGroups, Exercise>>(groups);
            exercisesList.BindingContext = ExerciseGroups;
        }`